# Trouble Creating a MySQL Function through PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I've created a CLI PHP script designed to allow me to run update scripts against my database.  The script works as expected, runs sequential update files, rolls back on errors, etc.  However, the only thing I can't get it to do properly is create functions. What am I missing?

---

**Script**

Here's the basics of how the script works:

```
$sql = file_get_contents($file);
$sql = "USE `$database`;" . $sql;
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

try
{
    $stmt->execute();

    if($stmt->errorCode() !== '00000')
    {
        throw new Exception("Error: Unable to run update $file\n" . print_r($stmt->errorInfo(), true));
    }
}
catch(Exception $ex)
{
    $pdo->rollBack();
    echo "Error: Exception occured running update $file\n" . print_r($ex, true) . "\n";
    throw $ex;
}
```

---

**SQL**

And here's an example of the Function portions of the SQL code:

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=CURRENT_USER FUNCTION `uuid_from_bin`(b BINARY(16)) RETURNS char(36) CHARSET latin1
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE hex CHAR(32);
  SET hex = HEX(b);
  RETURN LOWER(CONCAT(LEFT(hex, 8), '-', MID(hex, 9,4), '-', MID(hex, 13,4), '-', MID(hex, 17,4), '-', RIGHT(hex, 12)));
RETURN 1;
END ;;
```

If I run this code inside MySQL Workbench it runs as expected.  When I run it through my script using PDO everything except the functions are created and populated.  I get no errors and no exceptions.

---

**So Far...**

I've tried removing the definer, thinking that the user that was "CURRENT_USER" might be 'user@randomip' and the user in the system is defined as 'user@%'.

I also just removed the **definer** from the SQL.  Still works in MySQL Workbench, but not in this script.

I've also pulled the Functions out into their own SQL, same result.

---

**Other Info**

MySQL 5.5.37-0ubuntu0.14.04.1

PHP 5.5

When I connect with PDO I'm not setting the DB, since the script may need to create the database.  But the scripts are appended with a **USE** statement. Again all the other DDL statements work.

The user has all but **Grant** permissions on schema based on a pattern, specifically **ci_%**

---

**Solution, Update DELIMITER**

Updated the code to remove the **DELIMITER**

```
#DELIMITER USED TO BE HERE
CREATE DEFINER=CURRENT_USER FUNCTION `uuid_from_bin`(b BINARY(16)) RETURNS char(36) CHARSET latin1
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE hex CHAR(32);
  SET hex = HEX(b);
  RETURN LOWER(CONCAT(LEFT(hex, 8), '-', MID(hex, 9,4), '-', MID(hex, 13,4), '-', MID(hex, 17,4), '-', RIGHT(hex, 12)));
RETURN 1;
END;
```

Comment: What is the name of the stored procedure? You would normally `CALL sp_nameOfStoredProc;`

Comment: What permissions are you logging into the DB with from workbench and from your PHP code? Different users = different permissions sets.

Comment: @JayBlanchard This is a file with SQL Code that is defining a function, not a stored procedure.  One of the functions is listed in the question.

Comment: @MarcB It's the same user in both environments.

Comment: While not excecute mysql command line callas for this type of use case.  I don't believe that 'prepare' is approriate here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to use `DELIMITER` when you submit a statement through an API like PDO.

In fact, you *must not* use `DELIMITER`, because it's not recognized by the server's SQL parser. It's only recognized in the mysql client.

Comment: I had actually tried that before without success, and I guess stepping away from the problem and trying again I did something different.  Updated the question with the solved code. Thanks.